# Couldn't find a navigation object. Is your component inside a screen in a navigator?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-stack

In My below code when I use useNavigation() then it gives an error like my quiestion
How to use useNavigation, Please any one can solve this error... ERROR:Couldn't find a navigation object. Is your component inside a screen in a navigator?
I followed code from here https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/notifications#handling-interaction

```
import React, {useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
import { NavigationContainer, useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator, HeaderTitle, } from "@react-navigation/stack";
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App(props) {
     const navigation = props.navigation
    //const navigation = useNavigation();
    const [initialRoute, setInitialRoute] = useState('Splash Screen');

    useEffect(() => {
        messaging().onMessage(remoteMessage => {
            navigation.navigate("Description Screen");
            console.log(props.navigation)
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator
                initialRouteName={initialRoute}
                headerMode="none"
                screenOptions={{
                    gestureEnabled: true,

                }}
            >

                <Stack.Screen name="Splash Screen" component={SplashScreen} />
                <Stack.Screen name="Description Screen" component={DescriptionScreen} />
            </Stack.Navigator>

        </NavigationContainer>

    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: always double check that `useNavigation` get imported from `"@react-navigation/native"` I faced this same error because I was importing it from `"@react-navigation/core"`

Comment: It is a bad pattern to try to use navigation object outside of NavigationContainer. NavigationContainer should be the only component to pass navigation object on all child components, just like Providers. Because the mechanism is handle by this component, therefore implement all logics inside of NavigationContainer instead. You can work around if App is simple, if not lot of future troubles awaiting.

Answer (score 19):

You can't access navigation because it's not ready yet. you can create Ref for your navigation then export it and use it where you want.

```js
// App.js

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { navigationRef } from './RootNavigation';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>{/* ... */}</NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

`

Then you can use it by defining and exporting your method

```js
// RootNavigation.js

import * as React from 'react';

export const navigationRef = React.createRef();

export function navigate(name, params) {
  navigationRef.current?.navigate(name, params);
}
```

any way you can use `onReady`call back to say that your navigation is ready

```js
// App.js

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { navigationRef, isReadyRef } from './RootNavigation';

export default function App() {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      isReadyRef.current = false
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <NavigationContainer
      ref={navigationRef}
      onReady={() => {
        isReadyRef.current = true;
      }}
    >
      {/* ... */}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: You forgot about `isReadyRef` implementation in your solution above

Comment: export const isReadyRef = React.createRef();

Comment: This is not complete as noted, it has yet to be updated. So I'm just going to put a link to the original docs here in case someone has the same issue as I did. IT recommends a very similar approach. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop/

Comment: Where is the navigate(name, params) being called? This is code snippets without any cohesive understanding of the code flow

Answer (score 1):

To use navigate you need `NavigationContainer` to get initated and be ready.

You can change your code to call navigate from ref instead of hook, like this:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
import { NavigationContainer, useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator, HeaderTitle, } from "@react-navigation/stack";
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App(props) {
    const navigationContainerRef = useRef()
    const [initialRoute, setInitialRoute] = useState('Splash Screen');

    useEffect(() => {
        messaging().onMessage(remoteMessage => {
            if (navigationContainerRef.current) {
                navigationContainerRef.current.navigate("Description Screen")
            }
        });
    }, []);

  return (
    <NavigationContainer ref={navigationContainerRef}>
        <Stack.Navigator
            initialRouteName={initialRoute}
            headerMode="none"
            screenOptions={{
                gestureEnabled: true,

            }}
        >
            <Stack.Screen name="Splash Screen" component={SplashScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Description Screen" component={DescriptionScreen} />
        </Stack.Navigator>

    </NavigationContainer>

  );
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-container#onstatechange

```js
<NavigationContainer
  onStateChange={(state) => console.log('New state is', state)}
>
  {/* ... */}
</NavigationContainer>
```